# Using your own evaluation and training set in cloud-ml-engine sample

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, google-cloud-platform, prediction, tensorflow-serving

in the flowers tutorial by google here: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/flowers-tutorial
For preproccessing of data we used the dollwoing command:

```
python trainer/preprocess.py \
--input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
--input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/train_set.csv" \
--output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train" \
--cloud
```

I understand we could replace the csv file with our own list and hence train with a different set of images, however creating a csv files for over a 100 types of images will be cumbersome, is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

The train_set.csv is a list of file paths in Google Cloud Storage and the prediction label.

This is a part of the file:

```
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/daisy/754296579_30a9ae018c_n.jpg,daisy
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dandelion/18089878729_907ed2c7cd_m.jpg,dandelion
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dandelion/284497199_93a01f48f6.jpg,dandelion
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dandelion/3554992110_81d8c9b0bd_m.jpg,dandelion
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/daisy/4065883015_4bb6010cb7_n.jpg,daisy
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/roses/7420699022_60fa574524_m.jpg,roses
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dandelion/4558536575_d43a611bd4_n.jpg,dandelion
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/daisy/7568630428_8cf0fc16ff_n.jpg,daisy
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/tulips/7064813645_f7f48fb527.jpg,tulips
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/sunflowers/4933229095_f7e4218b28.jpg,sunflowers
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/daisy/14523675369_97c31d0b5b.jpg,daisy
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/sunflowers/21518663809_3d69f5b995_n.jpg,sunflowers
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dandelion/15782158700_3b9bf7d33e_m.jpg,dandelion
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/tulips/8713398906_28e59a225a_n.jpg,tulips
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/tulips/6770436217_281da51e49_n.jpg,tulips
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dandelion/8754822932_948afc7cef.jpg,dandelion
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/daisy/22873310415_3a5674ec10_m.jpg,daisy
gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/sunflowers/5967283168_90dd4daf28_n.jpg,sunflowers
```

So you will have to collect a set of images for your own train set, upload it to the GCS and clasify them. Then you just have to retrieve the list of path (it could be easily achieve using `gsutil ls` command) and concatenate with the classification label.